# Recognize a particular object and find a hole in it

Tags: python, opencv

①I  currently working on a project to find the 3D coordinates of the hole through stereo vision.

When I use cv2.HoughCircles, cv2 continues to find circles outside the desired object range.

I can't modify the parameters of cv2.HoughCircles because I want to detect only the circles inside the object in real time.

So I want to find the hole after cv2 recognizes the object.

Any ideas about finding objects? (I don't think deep learning like YOLO is necessary.)
Or is there a better idea than I thought.

The following is an image during stereo vision shooting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvIvb.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQKZG.jpg)

The code is as follows.

```
Left_nice = cv2.undistort(frameL, MLS, dLS)
Right_nice = cv2.undistort(frameR, MRS, dRS)

grayR = cv2.cvtColor(Right_nice, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayL = cv2.cvtColor(Left_nice, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blur_R = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayR, (3, 3), 2)
blur_L = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayL, (3, 3), 2)

right_holes = cv2.HoughCircles(blur_R, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=80, param1=50, param2=20, minRadius=20, maxRadius=45) # 420mm
left_holes = cv2.HoughCircles(blur_L, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=80, param1=50, param2=33, minRadius=15, maxRadius=50) # 420mm

right_hole_coordinate = []
left_hole_coordinate = []


if right_holes is not None:
    x = 0
    right_holes = np.uint16(np.around(right_holes))

    x_mean = np.mean(right_holes[0,:,0])
    sorted_holes = sorted(right_holes[0, :], key=lambda i: (i[0]>x_mean, i[1]))

    for i in sorted_holes:
        if 20 < i[2] < 60: # check the radius of the circle, ajust as needed
            # circle itself
            cv2.circle(Right_nice, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
            # center of the image...
            cv2.circle(Right_nice, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
            cv2.putText(Right_nice, str(x), (i[0] - 10, i[1] + 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            right_hole_coordinate.append((i[0], i[1], x))
            x += 1

if left_holes is not None:
    x = 0
    left_holes = np.uint16(np.around(left_holes))

    x_mean = np.mean(left_holes[0,:,0])
    sorted_holes = sorted(left_holes[0, :], key=lambda i: (i[0]>x_mean, i[1]))

    for i in sorted_holes:
        if 10 < i[2] < 60: # check the radius of the circle, ajust as needed
            # circle itself
            cv2.circle(Left_nice, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
            # center of the image...
            cv2.circle(Left_nice, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
            cv2.putText(Left_nice, str(x), (i[0] - 10, i[1] + 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            left_hole_coordinate.append((i[0], i[1], x))
            x += 1

point_coor = []

if (right_holes is not None) & (left_holes is not None):
    right_holes = np.uint16(np.around(right_holes))
    left_holes = np.uint16(np.around(left_holes))

    sorted_holes_r = sorted(right_holes[0, :], key=lambda i: (i[0], i[1]))
    sorted_holes_l = sorted(left_holes[0, :], key=lambda i: (i[0], i[1]))

    for i in range(len(sorted_holes_l)):
        xy_l = np.array((sorted_holes_l[i][0], sorted_holes_l[i][1]), dtype=np.float32).reshape(2, 1)
        xy_r = np.array((sorted_holes_r[i][0], sorted_holes_r[i][1]), dtype=np.float32).reshape(2, 1)
        points_4D = cv2.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, xy_l, xy_r)
        points_3D = points_4D[:3, :] / points_4D[3, :] / 4.6 # 5.6은 비례

        # circle itself
        cv2.circle(Left_nice, (sorted_holes_l[i][0], sorted_holes_l[i][1]), sorted_holes_l[i][2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # center of the image...
        cv2.circle(Left_nice, (sorted_holes_l[i][0], sorted_holes_l[i][1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.putText(Left_nice, f"{points_3D[0]}, {points_3D[1]}, {points_3D[2]/6}", (sorted_holes_l[i][0] - 10, sorted_holes_l[i][1] + 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (255, 0, 0), 1)
        point_coor.append(points_3D)

for i in range(5):
    print(i, i+1)
    print(np.sqrt((point_coor[i][0] - point_coor[i+1][0])**2 + (point_coor[i][1] - point_coor[i+1][1])**2))

print(point_coor)
```

② And I have another question, I think I used the camera matrix twice, is this also a problem?

1. The distortion was handled through cv2.undistort.

```
retS, MLS, dLS, MRS, dRS, R, T, E, F= cv2.stereoCalibrate(~~~~~)
Left_nice = cv2.undistort(frameL, MLS, dLS)
Right_nice = cv2.undistort(frameR, MRS, dRS)
```

2. The projection matrix is as follows

```
P1 = np.dot(MLS, np.hstack((np.eye(3), np.zeros((3, 1)))))
P2 = np.dot(MRS, np.hstack((R, T)))
```

Comment: A cleaner environment for your photos would definitely help, I remember I answered your question last time. Though again, I also did some work around because I also got circles outside of this thing you want to detect. I'll try at it again, but I think with this working environment, it might be hard to only detect that black rectangle.